# C Substitution Cipher

Tags: c, substitution

I'm creating a substitution cipher in c, reading characters from a text file and encrypting them. However, when I run the program, the text in the file is not encrypted. I'm not sure, however, what exactly I'm missing. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <ctype.h>



    void encrypt(char *inchar)
    {
    while (*inchar)
    {

    if (isalpha(*inchar) && isupper(*inchar))
    {

    if (*inchar == 'A') {*inchar = 'G';}
    if (*inchar == 'B') {*inchar = 'H';}
    if (*inchar == 'C') {*inchar = 'B';}
    if (*inchar == 'D') {*inchar = 'I';}
    if (*inchar == 'E') {*inchar = 'A';}
    if (*inchar == 'F') {*inchar = 'L';}
    if (*inchar == 'G') {*inchar = 'U';}
    if (*inchar == 'H') {*inchar = 'F';}
    if (*inchar == 'I') {*inchar = 'P';}
    if (*inchar == 'J') {*inchar = 'J';}
    if (*inchar == 'K') {*inchar = 'K';}
    if (*inchar == 'L') {*inchar = 'T';}
    if (*inchar == 'M') {*inchar = 'V';}
    if (*inchar == 'N') {*inchar = 'M';}
    if (*inchar == 'O') {*inchar = 'M';}
    if (*inchar == 'P') {*inchar = 'O';}
    if (*inchar == 'Q') {*inchar = 'E';}
    if (*inchar == 'R') {*inchar = 'S';}
    if (*inchar == 'S') {*inchar = 'N';}
    if (*inchar == 'T') {*inchar = 'Q';}
    if (*inchar == 'U') {*inchar = 'D';}
    if (*inchar == 'V') {*inchar = 'R';}
    if (*inchar == 'W') {*inchar = 'W';}
    if (*inchar == 'S') {*inchar = 'Z';}
    if (*inchar == 'Y') {*inchar = 'S';}


    }                     
    }
    inchar++;
    }


    int main (void)
    {


    FILE *inputFile;
    char inputBuffer[80];
    char *inputPtr = inputBuffer;
    char inchar;





    inputFile = fopen("code.txt", "r");


    if (inputFile == NULL)
    {
            printf("Failed to open\n");
            return(0);

    }

    while ((inchar = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)
    {
            putchar(inchar);
    }

    inputBuffer[strlen(inputBuffer) - 1] = 0;


    encrypt(&inchar);
    putchar(inchar);

    return(0);
```

}

Comment: Fix your formatting. What does 'file is not encrypted' mean (IOW, what results are you getting)? When you run this in a debugger (or add debugging output) what do you see?

Comment: The large block of `if`s should be `if else`s, otherwise you change an A to a G, a G to a U and a U to a D, which effectively maps all of A, G and U to D.

Comment: What I mean is its not encrypting. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: That it isn't encrypting shouldn't be a surprise. You only echo the file in the `while` loop: You read a character in and then print it with `putchar`.

Comment: I would suggest using `else if` blocks as M Oehm mentioned, or use `case` statements.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but you should think about replacing the 26 `if`s with something more elegant.

Comment: why don't use a lookup table instead of that inefficient long `if` list?

Answer (score 1):

The file doesn't change because your program does nothing that can change the contents of the file.

All you do is print (using `putchar()`) the encrypted character, there's no file writing code.

You should open a second file for writing, and write the resulting characters there. Then once you're done, you can rename the written file to replace the input if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with what you're doing (and what you're asking).

1. Your `encrypt` function is not really a shift cipher. A shift cipher is an encryption scheme with a key *K; K < alphabet_size* where each letter is replaced by the letter *K* positions up in the alphabet (wrapping around).  What you have with your `encrypt` function is more of a scrambling cipher.

   An actual shift cipher, with the key 6, for example, and the English alphabet, would look like this:

   `char shift_tbl[27] = "GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF"; // shift cipher with key = 6`
2. The "encryption" in your encryption scheme is not going to work.

   - The output `'M'` appears for two different input characters
   - There are two possible outputs for the input `'S'`
   - There is no handling for the characters `'X'` and `'Z'`
3. You are doing nothing to write the output back to the file.  Now, since you are replacing each single character with a single other character, this is easy enough to accomplish when overwriting the same file.

Here is a proper shift cipher implementation in C with the key *K = 6*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char shift_tbl_u[27] = "GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF"; 
char shift_tbl_l[27] = "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef"; 
char encrypt(char inchar)
{
        if(isalpha(inchar) && isupper(inchar))
    {
        return shift_tbl_u[inchar-'A'];
    }
    else if(isalpha(inchar) && islower(inchar)) 
    {
        return shift_tbl_l[inchar-'a'];
    }
    return inchar; // non alphabetic = no change;
}


int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("code.txt", "rb+");
    char *buffer = NULL;    
    size_t s_file;
    int i;

    if(!fp)
    {
        puts("Could not open code.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    s_file = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    buffer = malloc(s_file + 1);
    if(!buffer)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    fread(buffer, 1, s_file, fp);
    
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
    for(i = 0; i < s_file; i++)
    {
        char c = encrypt(buffer[i]);
        fwrite(&c, 1, 1, fp);
    }
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
    
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Example usage:

```
C:\Temp>cl encrypt.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

encrypt.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:encrypt.exe
encrypt.obj

C:\Temp>type con > code.txt
Hello World
^Z

C:\Temp>encrypt

C:\Temp>type code.txt
Nkrru Cuxrj

C:\Temp>
```

Now, you could speed up execution of this program by encrypting all of `buffer` before writing it back out to `fp` instead of encrypting and writing one character at a time, but you have the general idea now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors/little mistakes in you code:

1. It doesn't encrypt anything because you don't print anything, as
   someone has said in comments you just print the string you've read.
2. You also have done confusion with while loops in encrypt(): the execution was stuck at the start of the first one.
   **TIP: when you're not able to find where the program doesn't work, try to print a message in different points of its execution, this helps a lot.**
3. You don't need all that loops, just read the string and encrypt every single character (this works whith short sentences, to encrypt a long text this approach could take too much time).

The code below works, it take a string from a file and encrypt it with a simple substitution/transposition of 6 characters (e.g A --> G).

**NOTE: your previous substitution changed two different characters into the same**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encrypt(char inchar)
{
  //Changing chars
  inchar = inchar + 6; //This is a simple sobstution

  //print encrypted char
  printf("%c",inchar);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    char inputBuffer[80];
    char *inputPtr = inputBuffer;
    char inchar;
    int i;

    inputFile = fopen("code.txt", "r");

    //check file
    if (inputFile == NULL){ 
      printf("Failed to open\n");
      return 0;
    }else{
      //inputFile is valid so I read a string
      //and store it in inputBuffer
      fgets(inputBuffer, 80, inputFile);

      //pass every character of inputBuffer to encrypt()
      for(i=0; i<strlen(inputBuffer); i++){
    encrypt(inputBuffer[i]);
      }

    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I've not implemented any controls on characters format (uppercase, alphanumeric only, ecc...) and you could change easily the encrypting algorithm.

Comment: "simple substitution/transposition of 30 characters (e.g A --> G)"

In which character set is G 30 positions up from A?

Comment: Sorry I've not explained well that point: in ASCII char 'A' is 30 positions behind 'G', the code take a character and encrypt using a shift of 30 positions, it's a Caesar cipher with shift of 30 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: In ASCII, A is 0x41 (65) and G is 0x47 (71), so A is 6 positions behind G, not 30

Comment: Ok, now I've found my mistake I've read wrong the table, you're right, thanks